# How do i deserialize a json dataset directly from a file?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json file named "basic.json" with a bunch of hearthstone card information:

```
    {
      "Basic": [

        {
          "cardId": "HERO_09",
          "cardSet": "Basic",
          "collectible": true,
          "faction": "Neutral",
          "health": 30,
          "img": "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/original/HERO_09.png",
          "imgGold": "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/animated/HERO_09_premium.gif",
          "locale": "enUS",
          "name": "Anduin Wrynn",
          "playerClass": "Priest",
          "rarity": "Free",
          "type": "Hero"
        },
        {
          "cardId": "HERO_01",
          "cardSet": "Basic",
          "collectible": true,
          "faction": "Neutral",
          "health": 30,
          "img": "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/original/HERO_01.png",
          "imgGold": "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/animated/HERO_01_premium.gif",
          "locale": "enUS",
          "name": "Garrosh Hellscream",
          "playerClass": "Warrior",
          "rarity": "Free",
          "type": "Hero"
        }, 
etc.
```

I'm trying to deserialize the file and put the card objects into a dictionary data structure.  I've managed to do so by first converting the json file into a string and then deserialising as a dataset:

```
{

            string json = File.ReadAllText(@"filepath\Basic.json");
            DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(json);
            DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["Basic"];
            Dictionary<CardKey, Card> cards = new Dictionary<CardKey, Card>();


            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {

                cards.Add(
                    new CardKey((string)row["cardId"], (string)row["name"]), 
                    new Card((string)row["imgGold"], (string)row["img"]));
            }


        }
```

My question is, how do I deserialize the json file directly from "basic.json" instead of converting the file to a string and then deserializing like I did above?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a stream instead.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
  JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  // read the json from a stream
  // json size doesn't matter because only a small piece is read at a time from the HTTP request
  DataSet dataSet = serializer.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(sr )
}
```

You can read more about that here http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm